# Echo a variable if condition met

Tags: php

I just started with PHP... This works so far:

```
$value = get_field( "transmissie" );

if( $value ) {
    echo $value;
} else {
    echo 'empty';
}
```

The value variable can be "Manual" or "Automatic"

What I'm trying to do is to check if the value is "Manual" and then I want to echo 'Manual', but if the value is 'Automatic' then I want to echo this:

`<a href="https://www.example.com/automatic">Automatic</a>`

Can someone put me in the right direction? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is this question solved? Given the answer that is which looks like it hit the nail right on the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP and many other languages, `==` is used to test whether two values match. So in your case it's a simple usage of that operator to get what you want:

```
if( $value == "Manual" ) {
    echo $value;
} else {
    echo '<a href="https://www.example.com/automatic">Automatic</a>';
}
```

N.B. If you want to be sure that both values are of the exact same data type then you would use `===` instead. (e.g. `"1" == 1` will return true, because it considers that the string `"1"` is the same as the integer `1`, whereas `"1" === 1` will return false - it considers they are not the same because they are not the same data type.)

There's more information in the manual here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @user13537171 No problem. Just to check, do you now understand _why_ it works, and how to use the `==` in future?

Comment: Yes, I tried `=`, now I see I need 2 of them... or 3 ;).

I added an elseif if value is empty.

`<?php
$value = get_field( "transmission" );

if ( $value == "Manual" ) {
    echo 'Manual';
} elseif (empty($value)) {
    echo 'Unknown';
} else {
    echo '<a href="https://www.example.com/automatic">Automatic</a>';
}`